# Loop over plotly traces in python

Tags: python, pandas, plotly

I have a list of data frames `A[i]` where `i` goes from 0 to 50. If I want to draw traces manually, it works:

```
import plotly.graph_objects as go

fig = make_subplots(specs=[[{"secondary_y": True}]])
fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(x=A[1].index,y=A[1]['diff'], mode='markers',name='Line 3'),secondary_y=False,)
fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(x=A[2].index,y=A[2]['diff'], mode='markers',name='Line 4'),secondary_y=False,)
```

However, I would like to draw the column `diff` from each data frame of the list and I would like to do that in a loop, I tried the following:

```
fig = make_subplots(specs=[[{"secondary_y": True}]])
for i in range(0,50):
    fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(x=A[i].index,y=A[i]['diff'], mode='markers',name='Line 3'),secondary_y=False,)
```

This did not work, any ideas on what I'm doing wrong ?

Comment: what's your exact error msg?

Comment: @Ajay, no error but no output from jupyterlab. The cell is executed but I don't get any plots as an output.

Comment: may be try adding this inside your for loop. `fig = make_subplots(specs=[[{"secondary_y": True}]])`

Comment: @Ajay, I tried it, still no output

Comment: `fig.show()` must be inside the for loop

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
fig.show()
```

Kindly add this within the `for` loop.